# Makefile can we add a comment on a target line?

Tags: makefile

I realized that in with vim a comment is not highlighted when it is on the same line as a target:

```
mytarget: # A comment not highlighted
   @echo foo
```

However, it seems my GNU make 3.82 treat them correctly.

I checked the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Contents.html), but I didn't see anything related to a comment in a target line.

Why vim or Notepad++ doesn't highlight these comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vim (or any other editor's) highlighting is only as good as the highlighting code written for the editor. It doesn't necessarily reflect what is or isn't legal for any given version of the language/etc. in question.

That being said I have no idea if a comment at that point is actually legal or not. The documentation doesn't appear to say specifically.

*That* being said, empirically, it appears that all of make `3.81`, `3.82`, `4.0` and `4.1` accept a comment in that location.

```
$ cat comment.mk
all: prereq # this is a comment
        @echo '$@: $^'
$ /root/make/make-3.81/make -f comment.mk
all: prereq
$ /root/make/make-3.82/make -f comment.mk
all: prereq
$ /root/make/make-4.0/make -f comment.mk
all: prereq
$ /root/make/make-4.1/make -f comment.mk
all: prereq
```

Comment: They are legal there.  http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Contents.html says _Comments may appear on any line in the makefile, although they are treated specially in certain situations_ and none of the listed special situations applies here.

Comment: @MadScientist Indeed. Thanks for the clarification. I read that but somehow failed to merge that into its manual context appropriately to make that obvious. (I think I also assumed that the explicit treatment of comments in other sections might have affected this in some way but that is clearly not a necessary reading.)